# Images are not displayed and showing error like "cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha"

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone, ccsprite, texture2d

I am making an application using Box2D in which i am getting images from Asset Library and displaying them as sprites.

here is the code which i have done :

**Getting Images from asset library :**

```
CGImageRef imgRef = [[mutArrAssetPhotos objectAtIndex:i] thumbnail];
```

**Creating Texture2D :**

```
CCTexture2D *spriteTexture = [[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithCGImage:imgRef resolutionType:kCCResolutionUnknown];
```

**Creating sprites from textures :**

```
CCSprite *paddle = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:spriteTexture];
```

This gives me **warning**  in console like :

```
"cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha"
```

Still in simulator it works fine though warning but in device images are not being displayed.

But instead if i used :

```
CCSprite *paddle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"img.png"];
```

it is working fine and is not giving any warning also.

Can anyone help please ??   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think "cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha" is really a warning, just a notice. It didn't find any alpha values and chooses another color format that will be faster to draw. You could have created your images in that color format, turning alpha OFF before saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it.
Somehow i managed to recreate the image, from which i was creating sprite.

```
CGImageRef imgRef = [[mutArrAssetPhotos objectAtIndex:i] thumbnail];
        UIImage *image = [self updateImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef]];
        imgRef = image.CGImage;

        CCSprite *paddle = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
```

And for updating the image, i redraw it so that i do not get any alpha warnings.The update method is like this :

```
-(UIImage *) updateImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,50, image.size.width,image.size.height);

    image = [self captureImageFrom:imgView];

    [imgView release];
    return image;
}

-(UIImage *) captureImageFrom:(UIImageView *)view{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenShot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (could not find docs to confirm tough) that the thumbnail changes the image format so you get a plain no alpha image ref.

Try using the following for creating the right image ref :

```
CGImageRef imgRef = [[[mutArrAssetPhotos objectAtIndex:i] defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage];
```

Comment: But i need thumbnail images only , because i've lots of images to be displayed at a time and i can't display them with full resolution.

Comment: but did it work ? did you get those errors about the bits format ? If not than just scale the sprite to your desired size.

Comment: No , I tried fullResolutionImage. But it didn't work. Even with Scaling it's showing the same warning for image has no alpha.

Comment: It might be that your CCTexture2D is causing the problem. (btw I am not familiar with this texture init signature). Try creating the sprite using the imgRef object directly using spriteWithCGImage class method of CCSprite

Comment: Tried that also.. But still no success. The main problem is that in simulator images are being displayed and working fine. But in iphone its not at all being displayed.. :(